# How can I resize without distorting in Adobe XD?

Tags: layers, shapes, adobe-xd

I am using Adobe XD, I have created a progress bar, which I want to use in a different location with having a different size.

But when I am trying to do so, this is what happens:

[image: Video]

Comment: As far as I know, XD doesn't have a way to scale strokes or effects while transforming.  You'll have to set them manually after scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:
Select all shapes and group them. Then Go to **Object** -> **Path** -> **Outline Stroke**.

Hopefully, issue will be resolved!

Comment: It worked @Jawad thank you :)